# I need help to find card 094 in Fallout: The Board Game

Tags: fallout

I'm having trouble finding card 094. Card 016 says to add 094, but I can’t find anywhere. I've counted all my encounter cards and I believe I have them all. I don't know what 094 is meant to be or where I'm meant to find it.

Could someone tell me what kind of card it is, if it's a vault card or something else, and where in the game materials I'm supposed to find it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? Are you looking for the name of the card numbered 094 or 110 or...?

Comment: Card 016 references [094 and 134](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyuep.jpg), 094 should be among the box's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Card 094 should be included in the contents of the box.

If you are missing card 094 you can send a request to Asmodee for a replacement here : https://parts.asmodeena.com/partsrequests/